# iOS UITableViewCell releasing subviews

Tags: ios, uitableview, subview

I have noticed that `UITableViewCell` is not reusing it's subviews and seems to be released when scrolling up and down. I am creating `UITableViewCell` subview and animating it on `viewDidAppear`. I want to do this only once and then I expect subview to stay in the ContentView forever until view disappears. So I have done following which I think right way but not sure what's wrong; can someone help?

```
UINib *nib1 = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:nib1 forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
@property (nonatomic) CustomeView *customeView;

@end

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      static NSString cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
      CustomCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:accountCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ......

    customCell.customeView = (CustomeView*)[customCell.contentView viewWithTag:101];

   if(!customCell.customeView) {
      customCell.customeView = [CustomeView new];
      //configure customview...                                  
      customCell.customeView.tag = 101;
      [customCell.contentView addSubview:customCell.customeView];
   }

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is `accountsListBaseCell` ?

Comment: Edited it. It is actual cell name..I was trying to create sample.

Comment: How do you know its subviews is released when scrolling up and down ? I found you didn't set `customeView`'s frame when created it.

Comment: I am setting up it's frame and other configurations as well and animating it on viewDidAppear. When I scroll up and down if(!customCell.customeView) condition becomes true which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Log customCell when `!customCell.customeView` is YES, it should only go once for each customCell.

Comment: That's what it supposed to happen but it's not. It is going again for same section-row and creating customeView again which is I want to prevent!

Comment: I see that customeView is nil when it is going again inside (for same section-row for which it was created) the condition that means Cell is releasing subview customview.

Comment: I didn't find anything wrong with your code, but I think there is some redundant code. `customCell.customeView = (CustomeView*)[customCell.contentView viewWithTag:101];` this line can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your property type to strong:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CustomeView *customeView;
```

Comment: strong attribute is used by default.

Comment: This doesn't work either as KudoCC pointed properties by default is strong.

Comment: @AppleDeveloper: why do you use customeView as a properties? Why don't initialize it programmatically for every cell? Or just add it directly by using IB?